# How to use CASE statement with CakePhp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to execute the following select statement in CakePHP 3.X

```
SELECT
    ...
    (CASE WHEN declined_by = 1 THEN Customer WHEN declined_by = 2 THEN Admin WHEN declined_by = 3 THEN Both ELSE None END) AS `Declined_by`
    ...
```

But I doesn't want to use custom query`. I need code that included:

```
$query->newExpr()->addCase()
```

and `->eq() functions.

Comment: So what's the problem that you're facing? The how to is described in the Cookbook: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright!
finally, I got my answer.
Thank you for everyone.
here is my final query.

```
$query=$OrdersModel->find('all');   

$decline_member = $query->newExpr()
                ->addCase([$query->newExpr()->eq('declined_by','1'),$query->newExpr()->eq('declined_by','2'),
                $query->newExpr()->eq('declined_by','3'),],['Customer','Admin','Both','None'],['string','string','string','string']);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can run raw mysql query in cakephp

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute('YOUR QUERY')->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Comment: As I already mention that I don't want to use a custom query. I want to use the only function like newExpr()->addCase() and eq().